# implement azure Storage queues with ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to implement azure Storage queues with ansible but all what I can find in the docs is the Azure Service Bus queue!

Comment: Looking at the list of available modules [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/index.html#plugins-in-azure-azcollection), it seems Storage Queues management is not implemented. You may want to raise an issue [here](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.